# Problema al pasar variable de una vista a controller, laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

Hola chicos tengo un boton el cual esta enlazado a una ruta acompañado de la variable $id que recogo de un datatable, seguidamente tengo la ruta creada apuntando aun controller y una funcion a la que debería pasarse la $id pero me salta el error **Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\OperariosController::editarOperarioForm(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected** que basicamente me dice que esperaba una variable pero no la ha recibido.

**Boton con su ruta**

```
<a style="width:49%;float:left;" class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('editarOperarios', $id)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a>
```

**Ruta**

```
Route::get('/editar-operario', 'OperariosController@editarOperarioForm')->name('editarOperarios');
```

**Controller**

```
class OperariosController extends Controller
{
   public function editarOperarioForm($id)
   {
       $datoIndividuales = operario::FindorFail($id);
       return view('trabajadores.detalletrabajador', compact('datoIndividuales'));
}
```

}

**PD:** a mi la ID si que me pasa bien a la ruta ya que me sale la ruta arriba definida como http://localhost/rp-roblesl6/public/editar-operario?64  donde 64 es la $id pero en controller no entra.

Answer (score 1):

Lo correcto según las convenciones de Laravel es determinar dicho parámetro como requerido en la ruta, lo cual se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
Route::get('/editar-operario/{id}', 'OperariosController@editarOperarioForm')->name('editarOperarios');
```

Agregando `/{id}` haces que la ruta espere un parámetro de entrada, el cual tendrá como «nombre de variable», id.

Revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters

Comment: Agregado {$id} me da un error 404

Comment: Entonces utiliza el helper así: `route('editarOperarios', ['id' => $id])`

Comment: podria ser que al pasarse la $id en Json diese problemas?  ya que el boton lo recojo mediante esta funcion 
Route::get('operarios', function(){

    return datatables()
    ->eloquent(App\operario::query())
    ->addColumn('btn', 'actions/actionsEE')
    ->rawColumns(['btn'])
    ->toJson();
});

Comment: Poniendo lo que me has dicho anteriormente "route('editarOperarios', ['id' => $id])" consigo el mismo error de que se esperaba 1 parametro pero esta vez viene de dtatable